# Unchecked Return Value (veracode scan) for requesting authorizationStatus

Tags: ios

Could you please clarify why it is not passing the scan and returns error "Ignoring a method's return value can cause the program to overlook unexpected states and conditions.":

```
var authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus { 
 if(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {   
      let manager = CLLocationManager() 
      return manager.authorizationStatus // for this line 
    } else {  
      return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() // for this line
    }
 } else { 
    return CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined  
 }
}
```

I already added all possible checks, but still not passed